# Pass data Between functions in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, function, codeigniter

I have two functions and Im trying to pass an array of data to the function that have the view like this:

```
function one()
{
  $data['array'] = $array;
  $this->load->view('etc/asdf', $data);
}

function two()
{  
  $array[];

  return $array;
}
```

What Im doing wrong?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$data['array'] = $this->two(); // Instead of $array, as it is undefined
$this->load->view('etc/asdf', $data);
```

And also to define array you have to do following `$array = array();`, not `$array[];`

**Note**: You have to invoke function rather than specify `$array`, as it is returned from function called `two`

Answer (score 1):

```
function one()
{
  $data['array'] = $this->two();
  $this->load->view('etc/asdf', $data);
}

function two()
{  
  $array= array('1','2','2');

  return $array;
}
```

instead of `$data['array'] = two();`

use  `$data['array'] = $this->two();`